# How to increase the timeout when I have owned the cache lock in the AppFabric

Tags: c#, appfabric, appfabric-cache

Now I am trying to lock an item in the AppFabric Cache, and I want to hold the lock until my work is done, so I need to tell AppFabric don't let my lock be timeout when I have already owned the lock.
   My solution is to lock the the same item periodically even I have already owned the lock.

```
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        String value = cacheClient.GetAndLock("key1", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), out lockHandle, true) as String;
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
    catch (DataCacheException e)
    {
        switch (e.ErrorCode)
        {
            case DataCacheErrorCode.KeyDoesNotExist:
                Console.WriteLine("Key not found");
                break;
            case DataCacheErrorCode.ObjectLocked:
                Console.WriteLine("Object Locked");
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Others " + e.ErrorCode);
                break;
        }
    }
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

However there is a problem. The code is throwing a DataCacheException and the ErrorCode is ObjectLocked. That makes me unable to know if I still have the lock, because if the lock owned by another client, the exception is the same as the current one.
   Does anyone have a solution to solve the problem?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In the pessimistic concurrency model, a client explicitly locks an object to perform operations. When objects are locked, a lock handle is returned as an output parameter and is required to unlock the object. There a only one unique handle per locked object.

Locked objects in the cache can still be replaced by any cache client with the **Put** method and you can get items with **Get**. Cache-enabled applications *are responsible* for consistently using **PutAndUnlock** for items that use the pessimistic concurrency model.

So in your case, if you want to increase to lock timeout of a locked object, you can simply Put again the same object with the same timeout (by the same client, the "locker")